# How to achieve native functionality while using JS API with ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, screen, electron-forge

I'm trying to build a Screen Recorder using `ElectronJS` but when I implement the funcitonality using JS built-in API, it throws this notification

[image: Screenshot]

Whereas, Desktop applications doesn't throws error, Kindly refer me to the resource that interacts directly with Windows API using ElectronJS, or you can guide me how I can avoid this notification.

Help is appreciated.

Thank you

I tried using `MediaDevices`, `getDevices` and other set of JS built-in APIs to record the screen